# How to draw contour on image from csv file

Tags: python, numpy, csv, opencv, contour

I need to draw contour from a CSV file, I get each x, y lists alone but I need to create tuples to use them for a polyline function, but I get `'int' object is not iterable`!

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image5= cv2.imread("C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/code prjt/5_Vesicule.jpg")
cv2.imshow("im",image5)
cv2.waitKey()
centrev5 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/code prjt/centrev5.csv",sep=";")
print(centrev5)
cx=int(centrev5.get(['centreX'][0]) )
cy =int(centrev5.get(['centreY'][0]))
image = cv2.circle(image5, (cx,cy), radius=0, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=10)
cv2.imshow("centre",image)
cv2.waitKey()

point5 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/code prjt/point5.csv",sep=";")
print(point5)

for i in range(len(point5)):
    x=int(point5.values[i][1])
    y=int(point5.values[i][2])
   # transform x,y vectors to tuples
    c = [tuple(x), tuple(y)]
    img = cv2.polylines(image5, c, 1, (0,0,255),4)


cv2.imshow("contour",image5)
cv2.waitKey()


#print(c)

#c = [i for i in zip(x, y)]
#c = list(zip(x,y)) 
#[(x[i],y[i]) for i in range(min(len(x),len(y)))]
```

[the error is 'int' object is not iterable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msw75.png)

[result of x,y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScKVP.png)

Comment: does this `cv2.polylines(image5, zip(x,y), 1, (0,0,255),4)` solve your issue?

Comment: no, the problem is in the c = [tuple(x), tuple(y)]

Comment: try printing x and y and update your question to include the output

Comment: I understand that, I am suggesting you to comment that line `c = ...` and replace your `cv2.pol....` line with what I mentioned earlier

Comment: thank you for your helping, I did what you told me to do but it's the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to convert a int to a tuple her `tuple(x)`. x is defined to be an `int`. `int`s are not iterable. So it cannot be converted to a `tuple` direktly. If you want to have a touple which only contains `x` then use `(x,)` (beware of the trailing `,`).

`cv2.polylines()` expects its second argument to be in the form

```
[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...)]
```

and will then draw a polygon connection all points in the list.

This means that you don't need the for-loop. It's already integrated in `cv2.polylines()`. See [Here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html)

To bring your data into the correct format I would suggest the following:

```
points = [(value[1],value[2]) for value in point5.values]
```

and then draw the lines like so:

```
cv2.polylines(image5, points, 1, (0,0,255),4)
```